# django cannot compute sum on nested SUM

Tags: django, django-orm

I am running this query where I do `price*inventory1` and it works but when I try do do `price*(inventory1+inventory2)` django throws a error.

**this works**

```
        results = (
            Card.objects.values("rarity")
            .annotate(price=Sum(F("price") * F("inventory1")))
            .order_by()
        )
```

**this doesn't :(**

```
       results = (
            Card.objects.values("rarity")
            .annotate(
                price=Sum(
                    F("price")
                    * Sum(
                        F("inventory1")
                        + F("inventory2")
                    )
                )
            )
            .order_by()
        )
```

I am think I am doing something wrong. so, How can I do this in django ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to work with an inner sum, you can work with:

```
Card.objects.values('rarity').annotate(
    price=Sum(
        F('price') * (F('inventory1') + F('inventory2'))
    )
).order_by()
```